# React + Redux PUT api request to edit data in my redux store

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-final-form

My application is using redux to keep data from back-end API inside redux store entities reducer for example MEMBER object of data, which is shared across multiple components in App to display members details. Now I'm implementing *EditProfile* component which should take the data from form, send it as PUT request to backend API and if request ended successfuly **(Done till here)** **update current Member Profile entity in redux store**. I'm trying to find something like "best practice" to reach this redux store update. I have implemented basic api middleware (similiar to one in the Redux real-world application example), but I'm not totally sure, *how to reach the part with state updating.*

My backend api return after PUT request only a status code and a reason (if error) or memberId (if success). I'm not able to change back-end endpoint, to return new member profile object, because we have another "global" server beyond our web-server which works same as this one and I can't change it.

So I think I will need to persist data from Form (react-final-form) and in case of successful response which contains memberId (from backend), use this data to update current Redux store entity (Member Profile).

I was thinking about *saving update request data into store* entities reducer -> with a key like UPDATING_MEMBER_PROFILE and id request ends with success, merge this two objects into one and clear UPDATING_ part. Do you guys have any suggestion please?

**UPDATE:**

To call API in my code i have actions like:

**memberAction.js**

```
export const updateProfile = values => ({
type: API,
  payload: {
    url: "/members/update",
    method: "PUT",
    data: values,
    meta: {
      label: MEMBER_PROFILE,
      success: [], // action callbacks onSuccess
      error: [] // action callbacks onError
    }
  }
});
```

then my API middleware takes care of action.type === API and generate actions for API_REQUEST, API_SUCCESS and API_ERROR types, with entity and label from first fetchProfile actions. It looks like:

**apiMiddleware.js**

```
...getting Info from origin action about request here

next(action);
dispatch(apiRequest(entity, label));

return callApi(url, method, data)
  .then(response => {
    dispatch(apiSuccess(response.status, response, label));
    dispatch(success(response)); // Dispatch callbacks...
  })
  .catch(error => {
    dispatch(apiError(response.status, error, label));
    dispatch(error(response)); // Dispatch callbacks...
  });
```

and after middleware server and dispatch another actions my api reducer will assign data from API to store by entity like:

**apiReducer.js**

```
const apiEntitiesReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case API_REQUEST: 
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.payload.label]: {
          error: false,
          data: null
        }
      };
    case API_ERROR:
    case API_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.payload.label]: {
          error: action.isError,
          data: action.payload.data
        }
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

these are just pseudo codes to keep it simple (and i dont use thunks for now...). So I need somewhere (probably in api middleware) save temporary data into the store (probably by another action) to reach what I need by this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right path. Try dispatching one action for sending the request to the API and then (after success) dispatch another action to update your store. Something like that

**profile.js**:

```
export const updateProfile = newMemberProfile => { //your action, using thunk here
  return dispatch => {
   fetch(UPDATE_URL, {
        method: "PUT",
        body: JSON.stringify(newMemberProfile),            
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      alert("Profile update failed, please try again!");
    })
    .then(res => {
        dispatch(memberProfileUpdated(newMemberProfile));
    });
   }
}

export const memberProfileUpdated = newMemberProfile => {
  return {
    type: UPDATING_MEMBER_PROFILE,
    newMemberProfile
  };
};
```

Then add a reducer for this constant (put all the constants, and reducers in separate files for clarity)
**reducer.js**:

```
const initialState = {
    memberProfile: null,
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATING_MEMBER_PROFILE:
      return {
        ...state,
        memberProfile: action.newMemberProfile
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default reducer;
```

Don't forget to register your reducer in your configuration!
Hope it helps!

Comment: Hello Nikolay! Thank you so much for your answer. I just can't generalize it enough for approach that I'm using, which is fine becasue i didn't write anything about my approach.. I've updated my origin question with some code examples of my approach. Can i ask you please to look at it? Thank you so much!

Comment: It's little messy but, as far as I see, `action.payload.data` is your new profile. Just dispatch another action to update the profile (as in my example), and with another reducer set the new profile. And : `dispatch(apiSuccess(response.status, response, label));` -> maybe you have to replace second argument with `data` since you don't need response from server in case of success, but you have to pass new profile along to reducer, to update your store.

Comment: thank you so much :) I will try to play with it as long as it takes to make it work.

Comment: I have same question but the state part is an array. How to deal with that? I tried filter() but it doesn't work.

Comment: yaksh what do you want to do exactly?